# Where should be placed business logic in the three-layer system?

Tags: java, swing, hibernate, jsf

I know there are many questions about my problem and I've read a lot, but I'm still feeling little bit stupid, because I still haven't got it. So I'm trying it on my particular problem.

I'm implementing the school work. It should be a part of the information system, which has to be layered. We have to write it in Java or C# (I've chosen Java). We have to use two different data sources and two different views, in my case, oracle db and xml as data source and Java Swing and JSF as views.

According to the book "Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture by Martin Fowler" there are three principal layers:

1. **Data source layer:** I've generated entities using Hibernate ORM, I've created data access objects to implement simplier "interfaces" to getting the data.
2. **Domain layer:** ...
3. **Presentation layer:** I've created the Swing GUI and some .xhtml pages with MVC logic

If there wouldn't be any "calculations" in the system, but only simple achieving and returning data, I'm done, everything is ok. But I'm, for example, implementing the system, which should manage the competitions of the sport dancing, and during the competition I need to generate sets of couples for every round, after the competition I need to calculate points of every dancer, increment points if necessary and so on.

I know, that it is the responsibility of the Domain layer (business logic), but where in my code with? What names for these objects should I choose and where to put them in my code structure?

My structure:

- *hibernate.cfg.xml (configuration of hibernate)*
- *hibernate.reveng.xml (reverse engineering file of hibernate)*
- *isets.dao (package)*

  - *isets.dao.hibernate (package)*

    - *HbmCompetitionDao.java (data access object of Competition entity)*
    - *...*
  - *isets.dao.xml (package)*

    - *... (data access objects of another entities, which are stored as XML)*
- *isets.entities (package)*

  - *Competition.hbm.xml (generated entities)*
  - *Competition.java*
  - *...*
- *isets.util (package)*

  - *HibernateUtil.java (file to get session factory object)*

Where should I put my business logic and what should be the names of these classes?

Thank you very much for your help. Bye :-)

Comment: In the presentation layer you need to use _more_ layers. For example an MVC or MVP pattern.

Comment: You're asked to use two data sources and two presentation layers because this proves that you've built good data access with a separation of concerns and your presentation layer is separate from the rest of the system.  Just do the best you can to get your application working, and **after it's working**, you can more easily move functionality into the different layers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually domain layer means "entities" (models for domain) and domain services.

Entities hold all business logic related to them. Validations (checking that they're in correct state) and calculations are usually put in the property setters/getters, while operations for transforming data are exposed via public methods.

Domain services are classes that operate with multiple entities and do some calculations and/or transformations between entities.

A few things to consider. In order for this design to work properly (so it is testable, decoupled etc), dependency injection ([DI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)) must be used. Domain should never be bothered by getting or saving data etc. It should be clearly decoupled and all its dependencies should be known upfront.

If it is a simple application it may be wise to combine domain layer and data access layer, so objects that are created from ORM are already entities. Just add domain services (if you need them). Use then the same entities on presentation as well (as model for MVC). This will decrease the need for mappers to map between ORM made objects (lets call them dbos), entities and possible models needed for presentation. Of-course if you need different objects for each layer, by all means create them. Just don't over complicate if it is not needed.

Comment: Ok, does it mean that Hibernate represents two layers? Data source and domain layer? Of course the domain layer should be extended of my own business logic, e.g. when I'd like to recalculate points of the dancer, I would have the domain service object ServiceDancer inside the entity object Result which is responsible for saving results, and when I call for example `result.setRank(2)`, inside this method is called `this.dancerService.recalculatePoints(result)` or something like that?

Comment: If I understand you correctly: what I meant is that the same objects used for domain logic are used for loading and saving data with ORM (Hibernate in this case).

If you want to recalculate points of the dancer just add method to Dancer class called something like recalculatePoints. 

Point of "services" would be if recalculating points would affect other "dancers". In that case method for recalculating should go into a domain service. This method should then expect dancer in question and all other effected dancers (or a way to get them) as input parameter (remember -> DI)

Comment: Ok, I hope I've understood

Answer (score 1):

One of the possibilities is to structure you application as follows:

1) @Entity annotated POJO represent your data layer representing tables, relationships between them, etc using JPA

2) Stateless session beans implementing [Session Facade desing pattern](http://www.corej2eepatterns.com/SessionFacade.htm) wrap your container managed CRUD operations. There are typically one facade per entity, they usually look like this:

```
@Stateless
public class FooFacade extends AbstractFacade<Foo>{
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    public EntityManager getEM() {
        return em;
    }

    public void save (Foo entity) {
        getEM.persiste(Foo.class, entity);
    }

    public void reload (Foo entity) {
        getEM.refresh(entity);
    }

    //other similar stuff
}
```

AbstractFacade is an abstract class that provides genetic find and other operations that look identical in all facade classes (to avoid duplicate code). [This e-commerce sample application](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/entity-session.html#addSession) can be used as a great example of this strategy. The classes are usually named as EntityName + Facade.

3) Stateless session beans that realise your business logic (calculations for competitions in your case or adding goods into basket, implementing checkout, etc. for ecommerce app). Usually they talk to data layer via *Facade EJBs mentioned in part 2 above. [This part of the aforementioned tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/transaction.html) realises these EJBs.

4) Servlets to which your UI layer will refer their request. Servlets will utilize EJBs from part 3 to serve the requests.

5) UI layer - JavaFX, Swing, JSF, JSP, Apache Wicket framework - add anything you like.

Such a structure gives you both flexibility and scalability. Centring your business logic in stateless beans means you can scale well because they are pooled and every instance in the pool can equally be used when you application (e.g. servlet) needs talk to an instance of such a bean.

I strongly recommend you to thoroghly read through the ecommerce tutorial on Netbean's website to see the concrete implementation of this scheme. [Here is the download link for the source code of the application](https://netbeans.org/projects/samples/downloads/download/Samples%252FJavaEE%252Fecommerce%252FAffableBean_complete.zip), AffableBean ecommerce system, built through the tutorial.

Comment: Yes, it looks like good solution and maybe if I'd dicover "The NetBeans E-commerce Tutorial" earlier, I would use it. But now I'd have to start from the beginning. I'll rather stay with the Hibernate, but thanks. +1

Comment: you use Hibernate for your Entities as JPA implementation, right? it doesn't stop you from using the methodology provided because JPA is a standard and you use javax.persistence.* classes in your app rather than org.hibernate.* etc. For example, the above-mentioned tutorial uses Eclipselink instead of Hibernate. It has nothing to do with how you structure your business logic (stateless beans or some other way).

Comment: Yeah, I've got it, ok, I'll think about it yet... thank you again.